# How do you query @hybrid_property with an aggregate function in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, hybrid

here is my sanerio:
i have a model named Order:
i have some fields like that:

```
@hybrid_property
    def final_total(self):
        total = self.subtotal

        if self.final_discount_amount is not None:
            total -= self.final_discount_amount

        if self.final_tax_cost is not None:
            total += self.final_tax_cost

        if self.final_tip is not None:
            total += self.final_tip

        if self.service_fee is not None:
            total += self.service_fee

        return total

    @final_total.expression
    def final_total(cls):
        return func.sum(cls.final_total).label("final_total")
```

i want to get final_total of a record from database using query obj.

here is my query:

```
session.query(Order.final_total).filter_by(order.id=1).first()
```

i am getting error like:

```
python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py", line 1090, in _expr
    return ExprComparator(cls, expr(cls), self)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: In `final_total` expression defintion `func.sum(cls.final_total).label("final_total")` you reference to `final_total` that you defining, so you get infinite recursion.

Comment: thanks @jozel.i am new to python so can you please suggest me an example to solve this problom.

Comment: i replaced 
`func.sum(cls.final_total).label("final_total")`
with query as follows
`Query(Order.final_total).filter_by(id=self.id)`
but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it using hybrid_property but you can face huge performance problem because this `final_total` calculation will have to be done during query runtime...
Better option is to add new column `final_total` to you model (and db) and make this calculation when any of elements (e.g. final_tip, etc.) is changed and the result save in this new column.

However, if hybrid property performance is enough for you, this is implementation that should work:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
    
    @hybrid_property
    def final_total(self):
        total = self.subtotal
        if self.final_discount_amount is not None:
            total -= self.final_discount_amount
        if self.final_tax_cost is not None:
            total += self.final_tax_cost
        if self.final_tip is not None:
            total += self.final_tip
        if self.service_fee is not None:
            total += self.service_fee
        return total

    @final_total.expression
    def final_total(cls):
        return (
            cls.subtotal +
            func.coalesce(cls.final_discount_amount, 0) +
            func.coalesce(cls.service_fee, 0) + 
            func.coalesce(cls.final_tax_cost, 0) +
            func.coalesce(cls.final_tip, 0)
        )
```